# "Secrets were required, but not provided" when connecting to Wi-Fi from Raspberry PI 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, nmcli

I installed `nmcli` in my Raspberry PI 4. I connected to my local WiFi and after a while I got an image from my SD card. Right now I use that image file in another SD card with another Raspberry PI 4, but when I tried to connect to my local wifi I got this error:

```
Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

When I tried to connect to my phone hotspot it worked very well. Again when I tried to connect to my local network it wouldn't work.

I tried to delete my last connection and connect again but it doesn't work.

**Update:** I discovered that the internal Wi-Fi on the Raspberry Pi does not function well when the power supply is insufficient, such as when using a phone charger. This issue is attributed to the power management of the Raspberry Pi 4, resulting in errors. However, you have the option to use an external Wi-Fi dongle instead of relying on the internal Wi-Fi. This external dongle performs better in terms of sending and receiving signals and provides improved coverage.

Answer (score -1):

```
nmcli con delete "SSID"
```

Comment: I'm curious how deleting an (arbitrary?) connection named "SSID" would solve the problem of *"Secrets were required, but not provided"*. Also - the OP indicates that they "tried to delete my last connection and connect again but it doesn't work", so can you motivate this answer a bit?